# Unzip without path

Tags: compression

I would expect the following command to extract the *contents* of the top directory in the zip file to the destination directory:

```
unzip file.zip topdir/\* -d destdir
```

However, what I get is `destdir/topdir`. What I am looking for is an unzip command similar to

```
cp -r topdir/* destdir
```

How do I extract the contents without the `topdir` path?

Answer (score 6):

Try the `-j` option. From the man page:

> -j    junk  paths. The  archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the current one).

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, as I want to retain the subdirectories of `topdir` the `-j` option will not work.

Comment: The junk option is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!